# How to resolve this error in predict.SM$net.result : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, arcgis, qgis

I used compute function as it is not working in R version 3. I replaced it with predict as per the CRAN documentation but would not find the solution (Neuralnet)

```
compute.SM=compute(nn.ce,Rasters.df_N_scaled[,c(-1,-2,-14)]) # to let the variables matched 

out_SM <- data.frame(cbind(Rasters.df_N_scaled[,c(-14)], compute.SM$net.result))
str(out_SM)
```

> Error in compute(nn.ce, Rasters.df_N_scaled[, c(-1, -2, -14)]) :could not find function "compute"

```
predict.SM=predict(nn.ce,Rasters.df_N_scaled[,c(-1,-2,-14)]) # to let the variables matched 

out_SM <- data.frame(cbind(Rasters.df_N_scaled[,c(-14)], predict.SM$net.result))
str(out_SM)
```

I am getting an error as

> predict.SM$net.result : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

How to resolve this?

The `net.result` output is displaying as NA.

Please help me solve this